# Enable mt7601u WIFI dongle driver in kernel config

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, imx6

I have a IMX6 develop board. As default the Linux image does not included MediaTek mt7601u WIFI dongle, so I tried to add this driver using kernel config and recompile it.
I enabled the specific options as below:

```
CONFIG_WLAN_VENDOR_MEDIATEK=y
CONFIG_MT7601U=m
```

After boot the image I cant find this driver and my USB dongle still not working.
I'm using yocto 5.10-gatesgarth destro version.

How can I do this properly?

**UPDATE**

I use menuconfig interface and save it as customized.config, then using a .bbappend file for kernel and below script to define own .config file as kernel config file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += " \
    file://customized.config \
"
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG_tw-image-dev = "customized.config"
```

In the imgae script I have this:

```
inherit tw-irtu-core
inherit tw-dev

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    iw \
    wpa-supplicant \
    wireless-regdb-static"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += " mt7601u"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "tw-image-dev"
```

The image build successfully and my board boots too. When I execute lsmod to get loaded modules, the mt7601u not listed.

Comment: Did you edit the .config file, or use the menuconfig interface? You configured the driver as a loadable module. So after you build it, the loadable module has to be installed in the filesystem of the target board. Did you do all of that? Maybe you should simply configure the driver as a *built-in* module?

Comment: @sawdust I updated my question and add more descriptions. Please give me some guides.

Comment: "*When I execute lsmod to get loaded modules, the mt7601u not listed*" -- One more time, did you inspect the *filesystem* for the loadable module, the **.ko** file? One more time, maybe you should simply configure the driver as a built-in module?

Comment: Yes I inspect filesystem and I did find .ko file. I dont know how to configure it as a built-in module. How can I do it?

Comment: In menuconfig, a configuration selection will toggle between *unselected* (shown as a blank space), or *selected* (marked with an asterisk, `*`), or (for tri-state options) a *loadable module* (marked with an `m`). When a driver or feature is *selected* that means that the module will be built into the kernel image (aka static linking).